# JavaScript wrong timestamp formatting

Tags: javascript, date

I'm currently trying to format a timestamp in JavaScript. Sadly, the result is a bit strange. This is the date I'm trying to format:

> Thu May 23 2019 17:34:18 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)

And this is how it should looks like after formatting it:

> 23.05.2019

This is my code:

```
j = myDateString;
console.log(j.getUTCDate() + "." + j.getUTCMonth() + "." + j.getUTCFullYear());
```

But when I run my code, this is the result:

> 23.4.2019

Comment: Strings don't have those methods, so you can't be dealing with a string, you must be dealing with a Date object. Do you really want UTC values, or local?

Comment: @RobG Please remove the duplicate because it's not a duplicate. A duplicate is an exact question which has the same result. As you can see at your duplicate question, the outgoing is completely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the month is off. January is 0, december is 11, so add 1 to the month.
Secondly, you need a function that pads 0s to the left. Luckily, javascript comes with that.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

`'5'.padStart(2,'0')` outputs '05', for example

try this:

```
console.log(j.getUTCDate().toString().padStart(2,'0') + "." + (j.getUTCMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2,'0') + "." + j.getUTCFullYear());
```

[edit]
this function may not exist in older browsers, but there's a polyfill on the page I linked, and it's easy to implement yourself.

Answer (score 5):

`getUTCMonth()` starts from 0 (January), fix it by adding one.

`console.log(j.getUTCDate() + "." + (j.getUTCMonth() + 1) + "." + j.getUTCFullYear());`

Comment: Additionally, if you want zeropadded months you can use `padStart` like so: `(j.getUTCMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')`